# Is there way to use context on Server Component when pass a Server Component as a child prop to a Client Component

Tags: next.js, react-context, swr, react-server-components

I'm developing an applycation by Next.js13.
I want to get datas from DB and display lists with serching function.
I use useContext to manage what I want to search. I want to use this context as query of request to DB.However I can’t do it well.

I should use useSWR on client component?
Or you have another way to inform context to server component?